# Stream multiples parts of my screen

Tags: stream, split, screen

there is a way to split my screen in 4 stream?

For exemple, i split my screen in 4 equal parts, so I want to stream each one on a different channel, how can I get this? What tool use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use 4 instances of [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) and configure them with those 2 tutorials:

- [This one](http://grok.lsu.edu/article.aspx?articleid=14625) for streaming the desktop
- [This one](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=46971) for cropping the desktop